# Spring Boot jdbc issue. Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm just connected this DB in Intellij IDEA and it's fine, but when I launch my Spring Boot App with this configs, I see this trouble's messages

***Configs on pics

```
2019-05-28 20:56:53.487 ERROR 700 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 0
```

[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAPtw.png)
[pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdvmK.png)

Comment: Add a DataSource configuration class with the correct annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add a bean for DataSource in the configuration class, something like this

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource source = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    source.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
    source.setUrl(url);
    source.setUsername(username);
    source.setPassword(password);
    return source;
}
```